# How to include brackets in an acmart sigconf email address?

Tags: brackets, acmart, email

We have a lot of email addresses in a paper, and want to abbreviate them using brackets.  Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\title{A paper}
\author{Tom, Dick, Harry}
\email{ \{ tom, dick, harry \} @gmail.com}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

However, the brackets show up incorrectly:

[image]

I want it to succinctly say `{tom, dick, harry}@gmail.com`.

**Question**: How to include brackets in an acmart sigconf email address?

I tried using math mode for the brackets, using `\protect`, and using `\textbraceleft` and `\textbraceright`, but these just add additional problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Enter the braces as `{` and `}` (and not as `\{` and `\}`) in `\email` macro:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\title{a paper}
\author{tom, dick, harry}
\email{{tom, dick, harry}@gmail.com}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Explanation: `acmart` uses `\nolinkurl` for typesetting the email address.

Comment: Thanks!  Problem solved.  (Although, I feel a bit silly for not thinking to try this.)